# Using QTextEdit and html to display formatted log-text

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

I need to display a large (and increasing) log-file with QTextEdit (alternatively with QTextBrowser, must be one of those 2, though) and format the output in 3 columns with following properties:

```
1. column: text top-right aligned, fixed width, always 1 line (height depends on 2. column)
2. column: text left aligned, dynamic width (scales with window size), can be multiline with "wordbreak" (height depending on lines of text), can contain clickable URLs
3. column: text top-left aligned, fixed width, always 1 line (height depends on 2. column)
```

Is there somehow a way to use QTextEdit html markup (or something else, maybe) to achieve this and then simply append new log entries whenever necessary without recreating everything?

As a picture often says more than a thousand words I added an image of how I think it should look:

[image]